# Is it possible to disable the "Application has stopped." dialog that pops up on Android?

Tags: android, opencv, service, process, kill

I am trying to kill a service that is running on a separate process that is taking too long to run. It does get killed but the dialog "Unfortunately, Application has stopped" pops up. Since it's a separate process, it doesn't kill the main process and the application does keep running. But I need to do this multiple times (basically whenever the service goes over time), and the dialog pop-up is annoying. The service is running some OpenCV library code and that's what's being killed and why the dialog pop-up appears. Is it possible to prevent the dialog from showing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add your own Crash Handler in your project. To give you an idea [this is](https://github.com/stepango/droidkit/blob/f3140704b0a3577975167741a70eba6d9ee43947/src/main/java/com/lightydev/dk/app/CrashHandler.java) an example of custom Crash Handler you could modify for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think the intended way to stop a service is by using `stopService` or `stopSelf`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Stopping

Comment: Yeah, that is how I'm stopping the service